# laravel relationship's tables

Tags: php, laravel

I have 4 tables:

> user(id,role_id)
>
> role(id)
>
> permission_role(role_id,permission_id)
>
> permission(id, name)

User model

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use EntrustUserTrait;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    public function roles()
{
     return $this->hasOne('App\Role', 'id', 'role_id');
}
}
```

Role model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustRole;

class Role extends EntrustRole
{
    public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','role_id','id');
}
public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission','permission_role');
    }
}
```

Permission model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustPermission;

class Permission extends EntrustPermission
{
   public function roles()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role','permission_role');
    }
}
```

and i want to test in my controller to see if user have permission delete_article via if condition, any help? and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you **Role** model
Something like this you need to do (Many to Many)

```
//.......................
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission','permission_role''role_id', 'permission_id');
}
//......................
```

See **Many to Many** relationship: [Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

And to get the data into your controller

```
//..........................................
$user = get data with role and permission
$roles= $user->roles;
foreach($roles as $role){
   foreach($role->permissions as $permission){
      $permissiona_name = $permission->name;
   }
}
//...........................
```

first check with var_dump($user)

[Many to many with pivot](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) (see `Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns` section)

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withPivot('column1', 'column2');
```

See also "[Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)"